# laravel 8 API : how return user_id in store method with authentication?

Tags: json, laravel, api, foreign-keys, response

i'm building an API with laravel 8 ,

i have a Post table that has this columns :

`id`
`category_id` `user_id` `title` `body` `picture`  `study_time` `likes` `tags`

i want when a user that has admin or author level, and logged in admin panel , can add a post and in form , i show his/her username and i don't want  they changed this field(user_id).

and i don't know is it possible return it with JSON response or not?

how can i do that ??

my PostController :

```
public function store(Request $request )
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'category_id'=>'required',
            'title' => 'required|max:100|unique:categories',
            'body'=>'required',
            'picture'=>'required',
            'study_time'=>'required',
            'likes'=>'required',
            'tags'=>'null|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'Validation Error']);
        }

        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);


        $post = Post::create($data);
        $post->tag($tags);

        return response()->json([
        'data' => $post,
        'message' => 'xxx'
        ], 201);


    }
```

Comment: Many ways: simple one, is to find the user as auth and return it's username as part of the response.

Comment: i don't know how to return it as part of the response , as you see , in my response i passed $post , how  i return another part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => $post,
    'message' => 'xxx'
], 201);
```

Comment: as you see i did it.

Comment: I thought you want to return in JSON format, so I added ->json() in my response, which is the difference between my answer and your code

Comment: yeah sorry.. i forgot to edit my cod .. but i mean how call username from user_id with auth() and return it as json

Comment: if username is an attribute of the user model, then you could try `Auth::user()->username`, or `User::find(Auth::id())->username`

Comment: and how pass it  in json?

Comment: can i use compact ?

Comment: same concept `return response()->json(['username' => Auth::user()->username], 201)`

Comment: you are not returning view, why do you want to use compact

Comment: i want return $post ans $username as JSON . it is possible to return 2 variable?

Comment: yes, try this `return response()->json(['username' => Auth::user()->username, 'post' => $post], 201);`

Comment: If you found the answer is helpful, please accept it as the right answer

Comment: of course but there is a problem..  when it fixed i will  accept it